# HTC Incredible 2 clearing "App Associations" on reboot - why?

Tags: applications, settings, htc-droid-incredible-2

My Friend has an HTC Incredible 2 that is clearing all app associations whenever the phone reboots. Does anyone know what is causing this? I couldn't find anything on google, or my phone (an HTC Thunderbolt) that would lead to a setting or something.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "clearing all app associations"?

Comment: My guess is that it's about the 'default application' for a particular file type/protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Has your friend modified the Linkify app that implements the App Associations? Typically both the Linkify app that actually performs the association and the Settings app where you set them are signed by the system signing key. If the Linkify app was replaced with a modified version not signed by the system signing key, which is possible if you unlock and root your device, I imagine it would have trouble accessing the settings.